# Prove two harmonic function either intersect or the difference is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $u_1(x,y)$ and $u_2(x,y)$ be two harmonic functions in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that either $u_1(x,y)-u_2(x,y)$ is a constant function or there exists $x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $u_1(x,y)=u_2(x,y).$
}

My thought:

If there does not exist $x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $u_1(x,y)=u_2(x,y)$, then assume that $u_1(x,y)>u_2(x,y)$, consider $u_1(x,y)-u_2(x,y)$ is harmonic funtions in $\mathbb{C}$, then it has a harmonic conjugate, so it can be considered as real part of an entire function $g$. since the $Re g>0$, then consider $|e^{-g(z)}|=e^{-|Re g|}<1$, so by Liouville's Theorem, $g$ is constant, which means $u_1-u_2\equiv c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{C}$.

Is this the right way to solve this problem? I am not sure if I can assume $u_1>u_2$. Could anyone kindly help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Liouville's theorem states that a harmonic function that is bounded below on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is constant.

Comment: Well, the usual formulation of Liouville's theorem doesn't look like that, but it is equivalent...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So is my proof  using Liouville's theorem not correct? I used that If $f$ is a bounded entire function, then $f$ is constant.

Comment: My apologies, I thought you were looking for a hint. Your proof looks good. Let $g=u_1-u_2$, then either there is some $(x,y)$ such that $g(x,y) = 0$ or not. If not, then either $g$ or $-g$ is strictly positive.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for the hint and help.